# How to update cursor docs in MongoDB with pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How can I update the founded docs in MongoDB with pymongo?

For example: I have a dataset:

```
name    weight    amount
-------------------------
apple     2         3
banana    2         5
```

I want to get the weight of the fruits: weight * amount

```
name    weight    amount    total
-----------------------------------
apple     2         3        6
banana    2         5        10
```

How can I update the cursor documents ????

```
myFile = [
    {"name":"Appel", "weight":2, "amount":3}, {"name":"banana", "weight":2, "amount":5}   
]

myCollection.insert_many(myFile)

fruits = myCollection.find()

for fruit in fruits:
    total = fruit["weight"]*fruit["amount"]
    ????? What should I do now? ?????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the collection with the new field `total`, as below using [replace_one()](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.replace_one):

```
for fruit in fruits:
  fruit["total"] = fruit["weight"] * fruit["amount"]
  myCollection.replace_one({"_id": fruit["_id"]}, fruit)
```

Worth noting that instead of looping through the collection and saving a document one by one, you should also consider using [PyMongo Bulk Write Operations](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html), especially [Unordered Bulk Write Operations](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html#unordered-bulk-write-operations)

Depending on your use case, alternatively you could also use [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) to calculate the value server side:

```
db.fruits.aggregate([
  {$project:{name:1, 
           weight:1, 
           amount:1, 
           total:{$multiply:["$weight", "$amount"]}}},
  {$out:"fruits_modified"}
]);
```

The aggregation pipeline above, projecting a new field `total` with value of multiplication result of `weight` and `amount` field. Saving the result into a different collection called `fruits_modified`. 
You can then drop the `fruits` collection, and rename `fruits_modified` to swap in, for example:

```
db.fruits.drop();
db.fruits_modified.renameCollection("fruits");
```

Note that any operations being performed while the collection is being removed *may* be lost. Consider both methods, and use according to your use case.

Comment: Hi @Wan Bachtiar, thanks for the answer. But I still have a question with the "save()", I got the Warning: "DeprecationWarning: save is deprecated. Use insert_one or replace_one instead". So, If I use the insert_one() or replace_one(), then, I have to give a filter as the first parameter. Is it true?

Comment: I've updated the code to answer your question. Now it's going to search a document with matching [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) value and replace it with the calculated document.